# ErrorDocument 403 not working with an Alias folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following configuration in .htaccess

`ErrorDocument 403 /`

It works nicely if I'm restricting a subfolder that exists directly in the root dir, e.g. /var/www/html/sensitivefolder.

But if there's an alias in the .conf files and I want to restrict access to it:

`Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin`

The ErrorDocument 403 doesn't redirect to / and I get the standard page:

`Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.`

Is there a way to make ErrorDocument 403 work with Aliases? Thanks.
I'm using Apache 2.4.23.

Answer (score 0):

you can write below code in your .htaccess file

**ErrorDocument 403 /403.php**

or

**ErrorDocument 403 /yourdominname.com/403.php**

On seo this will show you 302 redirection on 403 error

Comment: In my case, I tried **ErrorDocument 403 /index.php** but it's still not solving the problem.

Comment: ping me nishantsaini0442@gmail.com

Comment: Then Use Second one

Comment: No matter what I throw at it, ErrorDocument 403 just doesn't want to redirect to anything when it encouters an aliased folder. Doesn't even work with a custom message as in **ErrorDocument 403 "forbidden folder"**